# Private Helm repo using CDK EKS

Tags: kubernetes, bitbucket, kubernetes-helm, aws-cdk, amazon-eks

CDK EKS model has a helm module making it possible to point out a helm repo, the chart and so forth.

I keep my helm charts in a private  bitbucket and is possible to use command-line helm to add that repo using credentials, like this:

```
helm repo add my-helm https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/myaccount/my-helm/src/master/ --username my@email.com --password mypass
```

How can I provide my credentials for my CDK stack to process the helm repo correct?

I use Typescript

Answer (score 1):

Just hit the same limitation. It is not supported at the moment see here: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/11031